# Update based on a select statement SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a select statement that gives me the results I need for my update but I have no idea how to incorporate it into the update. Below is the select statement and the results.

```
select top 20 percent
fpartno
,(fytdiss * fmatlcost) as 'total'
from inmast
where fpartno not like 'CRV%'
and fcstscode = 'A'
group by fpartno, fytdiss,fmatlcost,fabccode
order by total desc

fpartno                         total
---------------------------------------------------
1062-20-0244                172821.4800000000
B50602                      91600.7205800000
BM6031PQ                    82978.3200000000
LY2F-DC12                   74740.9500000000
BM6033SQ                    51640.4200000000
DTM06-6S-E007               49810.4700000000
```

My update looks like this

```
update inmast
set fabccode = 'A'
```

I'm guessing my select would some how go into the where clause but I'm not sure how.

Comment: So you want to set `fabccode` to `'A'` for all the rows from your resultset?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334712/update-from-select-using-sql-server.

Comment: correct the select statement gives me the top 20 percent of parts based on their totals.

Comment: Joe thanks for the link but I am not using to tables so I don't believe a join would work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating `top 20 percent` is tricky... because you can't put an `order by` in an update.

I would do something like this:

```
select *
-- update t set fabccode='a'
from inmast t
where fpartno in (
    select top 20 percent fpartno
    from inmast t
    where fpartno not like 'CRV%'
    and fcstscode = 'A'
    group by fpartno, fytdiss,fmatlcost,fabccode
    order by (fytdiss * fmatlcost) desc)
```

Run this is a `select` and make sure it works for you as expected.  If yes, then you can just remove the `select` line, and uncomment the `update` line.

Alternate solution:

```
select *
-- update t set fabccode='a'
from inmast t
join (select top 20 percent fpartno
      from inmast t
      where fpartno not like 'CRV%'
      and fcstscode = 'A'
      group by fpartno, fytdiss,fmatlcost,fabccode
      order by (fytdiss * fmatlcost) desc) x
on t.fpartno = x.fpartno
```

Comment: Jiggs this is great I didn't know you could do a join on a table and a select statement. If nothing else I will have to play with that. It could open up a whole new world for me.

Comment: Glad to help.  If you're learning, also check into `WHERE EXISTS (...)` -- it's great for filtering (and fast), but it doesn't work with `TOP` statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
update inmast
set fabccode = 'A'
where fpartno in (
select top 20 percent
fpartno
from inmast
where fpartno not like 'CRV%'
and fcstscode = 'A'
group by fpartno, fytdiss,fmatlcost,fabccode
order by (fytdiss * fmatlcost) desc)
```

Comment: there is no total column, its a calculation, your order by will throw an error.

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry. Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

I like using CTEs as they tend to be more maintainable, they're (in my opinion) far more readable, and they seem to perform as well as nested SQL statements and oftentimes perform better (ymmv).

```
;WITH CTE_Updates AS
    (
    SELECT TOP 20 PERCENT
         fpartno
        ,(fytdiss * fmatlcost) AS 'total'
    FROM 
        inmast
    WHERE 
        fpartno NOT LIKE 'CRV%' AND 
        fcstscode = 'A'
    GROUP BY fpartno, fytdiss,fmatlcost,fabccode
    ORDER BY total DESC
    )
UPDATE CTE_Updates
SET fabccode = 'A'
```